# how to add option into select and to prevent the drop-down box from disappearing on a click event of select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my case, l need to add option into select when click the `<select>`

Now l have a `<select>` like this

```
<select class="form-control" name="commentid" id="">
    <option value="">select</option>
</select>
```

and js code like this

```
$("select[name=commentid]").click(function(){
    $.get(
        "url",
        function(data){
            $("select[name=commentid] option:not(:eq(0))").remove();
            $.each(data, function(k, v){
                $("select[name=commentid]").append($("<option></option>").attr("vlaue", v.id).text(v.name))
            })
        }, "json"
    )
})
```

option updated when l clicked the select, but also disappeared of drop-down box

l found out that `append()` cased the drop-down to disappear, but l not know how to solve it

Comment: what you mean by disappeared of drop-down box?

Comment: under normal case, you click a select, the drop down will display, and you can select an option. But in this case,  select displayed, then disappeared immediately

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("select[name=commentid]").click(function () {
                var myOptions = [
                                    { 'val': "Value 1", 'text': "Text 1" },
                                    { 'val': "Value 2", 'text': "Text 2" },
                                    { 'val': "Value 3", 'text': "Text 3" }
                                ];

                $(myOptions).each(function (idx, obj) {
                    //console.log(idx);
                    //console.log(obj.text);
                    $('#commentid').append($('<option>', { value: obj.val, text: obj.text }));

                });
            })
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<div>
    <select class="form-control" name="commentid" id="commentid">
    <option value="">select</option>
</select>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but it has some difference with my problem. l want to add option when click `select` tag, not change event of select

Comment: I have edited answer according you when you click select it will add options .

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You only use multiple attribute for select but it's not show the dropdown button.
I suggest you `selectpicker` to solve your issue.
Read example [here](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#multiple-select-boxes)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are trying to do in here is to update the options of the select control on the `click` event of the select control.

So, what is happening is that when ever you click on the select control (either the options in the select control or the control itself) the value selected is not shown on the click which i assume you are considering as disappeared.

The reason behind that is your `click` function as you have bind the `click` function on the select control(parent) and because of this `event bubbling` is happening which is firing up the parent `click` event from child.

So, if you click on your option in the select control it will still call the parent `click` function as the child is a part of the parent's scope and as a result you will always see the default option(as in the function you are re-creating the options for the select) and you will not be able to see the selected option.
So, a better approach would be to call the `select option populate function` from a different event instead of making a call from it self. If you happen to have another event making a change to the particular select box that would be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$(function(){
    $("select[name=commentid]").click(function(e){
        if($(this).children('option').length <= 1){
            $.getJSON( "//www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bUHzakaaDC", function(data){
                $.each(data, function(k,v){               
                    $('select[name=commentid]').append($('<option>', {  value: v.id, text : v.name }));
                });
            });
        }
    });        
});
```

```css
select{border: 1px solid #999; padding: 5px; width:125px}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="commentid" id="">
    <option value="">select</option>
</select>
```